# How do I get my build to succeed in xcode after I include Flurry analytics?

Tags: iphone, analytics, flurry

I've included the folder labeled 'Flurry' in my project.  I've added the lines in AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "Flurry.h"

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [Flurry startSession:@"my_key"];
}
```

However, I get 7 errors after I try to run.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress", referenced from:
      +[FlurryReachability flurryReachabilityWithAddress:] in libFlurry.a(libFlurry.a-i386-master.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName", referenced from:
      +[FlurryReachability flurryReachabilityWithHostName:] in libFlurry.a(libFlurry.a-i386-master.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags", referenced from:
      -[FlurryReachability flurryCurrentReachabilityStatus] in libFlurry.a(libFlurry.a-i386-master.o)
      -[FlurryReachability isFlurryReachable] in libFlurry.a(libFlurry.a-i386-master.o)
      -[FlurryReachability isFlurryConnectionRequired] in libFlurry.a(libFlurry.a-i386-master.o)
      -[FlurryReachability isFlurryConnectionOnDemand] in libFlurry.a(libFlurry.a-i386-master.o)
      -[FlurryReachability isFlurryUserInterventionRequired] in libFlurry.a(libFlurry.a-i386-master.o)
      -[FlurryReachability isFlurryReachableViaWWAN] in libFlurry.a(libFlurry.a-i386-master.o)
      -[FlurryReachability isFlurryReachableViaWiFi] in libFlurry.a(libFlurry.a-i386-master.o)
      ...
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[FlurryReachability flurryStartNotifier] in libFlurry.a(libFlurry.a-i386-master.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:
      -[FlurryReachability flurryStartNotifier] in libFlurry.a(libFlurry.a-i386-master.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[FlurryReachability flurryStopNotifier] in libFlurry.a(libFlurry.a-i386-master.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Make sure in Build Phases under 'Compile Sources' all the Flurry implementation (.m) files are there, if not, add them.

Comment: From the Flurry iPhone SDK, in the Flurry folder there is only a file named Flurry.h and libFlurry.a.  I don't see the Flurry.m anywhere in the folder.  Where would this be located in the downloaded SDK?

Comment: @sharataka libFlurry.a is the equivalent of the .m file. I'm working on an answer.

Comment: @ErwaySoftware When I try to view contents of libFlurry.a in xcode, I can only see an image that says 'Archive' in the pane.  When I click on flurry.h, I can see the actual code.  Not sure if this helps.

Comment: @sharataka That's not your problem. See answer.

Comment: I really recommend [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org) to help manage library dependencies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting these errors because Flurry.h/.a reference the framework `SystemConfiguration.framework`, and you haven't added it to your project.

To add it to your project, select your project in Xcode (very top in the navigation thing on the left), and select your target. Scroll down to the heading 'Linked Frameworks and Libraries'. There will be a list of items with little toolboxes next to them. Click the plus button at the bottom of that list.

In the resulting popover thing, search for 'SystemConfiguration'. Double click on it.

*Repeat for Each Target*

Run your project. Get build succeeded. Done.

Comment: Fantastic!  I added SystemConfiguration and I'm able to build successfully now.  However, I'm not clear on what you mean by 'Repeat for Each Target'.

Comment: @sharataka If you have multiple targets in your app, you'd know what that means. If not, just disregard it.

Comment: @Gorky add security.framework to your project , it works for me after adding security framework , Thanks